# Determine the density of the liquid in kg/m3.

Tags: unit-of-measure, chemistry

I got this question on my homework and completed it, however, I would just like to check if my answer is correct or not. I need to convert it to units of cubic meters.

Density = 0.81 g/mL
1 gram = 0.001 kilograms    1 milliliter = 1e-6 cubic meters
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to convert your density to units of kg/m$^3$ or what is the assignment?

Comment: Yes, convert it to units of kg/m3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the $0.81$ g/ml.  Your division is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in converting units...The full answer is in $kg/m^3$

$$0.81*1000=8.1 \frac{kg}{m^3}$$